# GraphQL+Go file upload error with Scalar Upload

Tags: go, file-upload, graphql, mutation, gqlgen

I need to upload a file using GraphQL.  I declare a Scalar Upload to do this in a `.graphqls` file:

```
Scalar Upload

Mutation {
    ...
}
```

But when I try to make a request to the server, I get an error:

```
Unknown type “Upload”
```

How can I fix this error and correctly make a request to the Go server

I already changed the name of the variable on 'FileUpload'

Comment: i dont get what `Scalar`means ? is it a go type? please give us more info on what you are trying to do - links to what you are doing also helps :)